# Scipy's differential_evolution not running in multiple cores despite setting the workers parameter

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing, differential-evolution

I want to run in multiple cores scipy's `differential_evolution` function with the `workers` parameter.

I have followed the instructions of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) and developed the following script to check the running time of the function both with and without the use of the `workers` parameter:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution, rosen
    bounds = [( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 )]

    print( 'Beginning optimisation without parallelisation' )
    start = time.time()
    result = differential_evolution( rosen, bounds,
                                     workers=1,
                                     popsize=200,
                                     maxiter=1000,
                                     tol=0.001,
                                     seed=1 )
    end = time.time()
    print( 'Optimisation finished after {} seconds'.format( round( end - start, 2 ) ) )

    print( '\nBeginning optimisation with workers parameter set to 10' )
    start = time.time()
    result = differential_evolution( rosen, bounds,
                                     updating='deferred',
                                     workers=10,
                                     popsize=200,
                                     maxiter=1000,
                                     tol=0.001,
                                     seed=1 )
    end = time.time()
    print( 'Optimisation finished after {} seconds'.format( round( end - start, 2 ) ) )
```

After running the script, these are the running times returned for each call:

```
Beginning optimisation without parallelisation
Optimisation finished after 59.0 seconds

Beginning optimisation with workers parameter set to 10
Optimisation finished after 60.43 seconds
```

As you can see, the execution with the workers parameter set to 10 is even slower than the first one. Can you help me with this? Is there anything else that I need to do in order to implement the parallelisation in the `differential_evolution` function?

I am currently using Python 3.8 and my `scipy` version is 1.8.1.

Comment: Overhead. The function evaluation is too fast compared to the overhead to provide a notable increase in speed with multiple processes.

Comment: I ran your code myself, with similar results. Then I changed `rosen` to a manual function, added a (non-sensible) loop in that function to increase the calculation time, and I found a noticeable speed-up with multiprocessing enabled (though not by a factor of `workers`). So the multiprocessing option only becomes useful for computation-heavy functions (apparently, the Rosen function is still too light).

Comment: To add: it looks like SciPy runs a new process for every population member separately (up to `workers` processes at the same time, of course). That means `N * popsize` processes overall, so there's also that amount of overhead. It would, of course, have been far more efficient if SciPy divided `N * popsize` over `workers` processes, and spread the calculations to `N * popsize / workers` trials inside each process, reducing the overhead significantly. But this is my guess from glancing at the source code; I may be mistaken.

Comment: @9769953, you're incorrect in your first statement. scipy takes the efficient method you specify. The calculations are spread over `N * popsize / workers`, where `workers` is an `int` you specify. e.g. `workers=2` spreads the calculations over two processes.

Answer (score 0):

@9769953 is correct. There is overhead introduced by `multiprocessing`: creation of processes, parceling out the computations to the subprocesses, etc. This overhead is only overcome if the computation is CPU intensive, which `rosen` isn't.

If you have scipy >1.9 and if your objective function can be vectorised, then vectorisation may offer a speed gain. If you can eliminate intermediate calculations in the vectorisation, that are common to the entire calculation, then the gains will be larger:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution, rosen

bounds = [( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 ), ( 0, 2 )]


print( 'Beginning optimisation without parallelisation' )
start = time.time()
result = differential_evolution( rosen, bounds,
                                 workers=1,
                                 popsize=200,
                                 updating='deferred',
                                 seed=1 )
end = time.time()
print( f'Optimisation finished after {end - start} seconds')
   
print( '\nBeginning optimisation with vectorisation' )
start = time.time()
result = differential_evolution( rosen, bounds,
                                 updating='deferred',
                                 popsize=200,
                                 seed=1,
                                 vectorized=True
                               )
end = time.time()
print( f'Optimisation finished after {end-start} seconds')
```

gives:

```
Beginning optimisation without parallelisation
Optimisation finished after 46.94838500022888 seconds

Beginning optimisation with vectorisation
Optimisation finished after 40.34918713569641 seconds
```